# Is there anyway to have an UpdatePanel update after a button click, but before the methods in the button click occur?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, updatepanel

What I have is an ASP.NET 2.0 web application that allows the user to upload a .CSV

The html input type is submit.

I want to know if there is a way I can update my UpdatePanel that is below the input to show a little "Processing" .gif before my onserverclick method takes place.

I have tried putting a reference to another event at the beginning of that event, as well as other methods, but I'm getting no luck. From what I understand the method needs to finish before my UpdatePanel will refresh.

Here is some code for you guys

```
          <div class=" content-div">
              <input type="file" id="File1" name="File1" runat="server" />
              Select file Type:
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfileupload" runat="server">
                 <asp:ListItem>CSV</asp:ListItem>
              </asp:DropDownList>
           </div>

           <div class=" content-div">

              <input type="submit" id="Submit1" value="Upload File" runat="server" onserverclick="Submit1_ServerClick"
                 style="border-top-style: groove; border-right-style: groove; border-left-style: groove;
                 border-bottom-style: groove" />

              <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True"
                 Visible="False"></asp:Label>

                 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the event behind the code:

```
protected void Submit1_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddProcessGif();
        // Logic from submit button here that uploads .csv
    }
```

AddProcessGif() is a method that programatically adds my .gif and stuff. And it works, I have seen it fire, but only after my upload finishes, which defeats the purpose.

I don't have a very well written application here and I'm pretty new to ASP.NET, so I am not sure how to effectively make a progress bar or anything like it.

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Initiate your loading gif in JavaScript on the page with the click event.

Comment: How would I call a javascript method from my C#? Or how would I go about doing this?

Comment: The click event is in c#

Comment: @GrantH. my onclick event needs to be in C#, as that has all of my upload code in it. Is there a way to call c# events from JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can call a c# server side method from javascript.
what you need to do is add a scriptmanaget in your aspx page and set EnablePageMethods to true.

```
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

also your C# method has to be a [WebMethod] like

```
[WebMethod]
public static string DoSomething(string str1, string str2)
{
    string result = "This is concatenation of " + str1 + " and " + str2 + "'.";
    return result;
}
```

and then add the javascript function in your aspx page to call C# server side DoSomething method

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DoSomthing() {
        var str1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtstr1.ClientID %>').value;
        var str2 = document.getElementById('<%=txtstr2.ClientID %>').value;
       //Here we call server side methode
        PageMethods.DoSomeThing(str1, str2, onSucess, onError); 
        function onSucess(result) {
            alert(result);
        }

        function onError(result) {
            alert('Something wrong.');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! I will try this as soon as I get a chance